# replace entites in rawurlencode i.e. &lt; &gt; &quot;

Tags: php, str-replace, rawurl

I have the following code

```
<a href="snippet:add?code=<?php echo rawurlencode($snippet->snippet_content); ?>Save snippet</a>
```

where

```
'$snippet = &lt;a rel=&quot;nofollow&quot; href=&quot;http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&amp;url=&lt;?php the_permalink(); ?&gt;&quot; title=&quot;Submit this post to Digg&quot;&gt;Digg this!&lt;/a&gt;'
```

How could I get rawurlencode to replace "&lt"; to a "<"?

Many thanks in advance

rob

updated

using

```
<?php echo rawurlencode(html_entity_decode($snippet->snippet_content)); ?>
```

as suggested by the posters below, thankyou fixes the changing &lt ; to "<" but inserts \ throughout the snippet

```
<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://delicious.com/post?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title($id)); ?>\" title=\"Bookmark this post at Delicious\">Bookmark at Delicious</a>
```

the output I'm seeking is without the backslashes aswell

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://delicious.com/post?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title($id)); ?>" title="Bookmark this post at Delicious">Bookmark at Delicious</a>
```

cheers rob

FIXED

Thankyou to all who posted!

```
<?php echo rawurlencode(htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($snippet->snippet_content))); ?>
```

works a charm,

many thanks rob

Comment: Please edit your question so that your code is visible. Surround it with ` marks or put 4+ spaces in front of each line of code.

Comment: Thanks. You say that `html_entity_decode()` is still giving you some trouble. Can you edit again to show the html output you see after using it AND show what you would want that output to be?

Answer (score 4):

[`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) has nothing to do with converting to/from html-encoding. It performs URL encoding. The matching function to decode is [`rawurldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php), but again, that is not what you're looking for here.

The `&lt;` encoding is html-encoding. To handle that, you want [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to decode or [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode.

Basic usage for the above sets of functions is:

```
$urlEncodedStr  = rawurlencode($str);
$urlDecodedStr  = rawurldecode($str);
$htmlEncodedStr = htmlentities($str);
$htmlDecodedStr = html_entity_decode($str);
```

To combine them together you would do some combination:

```
$urlEncodedHtmlDecodedStr  = rawurlencode(html_entity_decode($str));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [the `html_entity_decode()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to escape a `&lt;` to `<`.

But since this is a URL argument, you need to call `rawurlencode()` afterward, i.e.

```
<?php echo rawurlencode(html_entity_decode($snippet->snippet_content)); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, if I use html_entity_decode then the code is printed/displayed on the page before the link text "Save Snippet". Any ideas?

cheers rob

Comment: As background the '<a href="snippet:add' link type is much like the iTMS iTunes link allowing you to launch Snippet app if you have this installed and insert a snippet ($snippet) from a webpage.

I've tried stripslashes, etc to no avail. rawurlencode at least keep the line breaks intact.

cheers rob

Comment: Hey thanks, how would I go about calling both functions in this case?

cheers rob

Comment: Thankyou, I tried

'<?php echo rawurlencode(html_entity_decode($snippet->snippet_content)); ?>'

the output is now converted correctly but slashes are inserted -

'<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://delicious.com/post?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title($id)); ?>\" title=\"Bookmark this post at Delicious\">Bookmark at Delicious</a>'

Any suggestions? 

cheers rob

Comment: @Rob: Not reproducible. You could add a `stripslashes()` if you like.